# Rendering HTML files from assets folder in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-webview, android-assets

I am an Android newbie and have been futzing around with trying to render an html file in my assets folder and getting a blank webView screen when my app runs in the emulator. Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    String filePath = "file///android_asset/www/index.html";
    //String filePath = "http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageregion.php";
    File file = new File(filePath);

    if(file.exists()){
        Log.d("WebView",filePath);
    }
    Log.d("WebView",filePath);
    WebView.loadUrl(filePath);
}
```

The commented out filePath works as it is calling an external web page. The file.exists() condition does not seem to print the file path in the logs. However, the second one below does. It looks like according to AS, the file does not exist. But i can see it in my folder with is under src/main/assets.

There seems to be many questions asked about this like what can be found [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/11/assets-folder-in-android-studio.html) They seem to demonstrate a working concept and what i have above appears to match the prevailing method for rending an HTML file in Android.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
String filePath = "file:///android_asset/www/index.html";
```

Instead of:

```
String filePath = "file///android_asset/www/index.html";
```

Looks like you forgot the dots `:` after `file`

Comment: Ah yes that confounded colon. Clever catch @donfuxx.

Comment: how to create assets folder in android studio outside the res